# Unable to Access Certain LDAP DirectoryEntry Properties in C#

Tags: c#, ldap, comexception, directoryentry

I've been bumping my head over this for a while. I've found many questions asked regarding this on the internet but none had an actual answer.

My goal is to read & copy certain properties from one object in LDAP to another.
I can do it for all the properties without a problem, except for one property. Trying to access that specific property from a DirectoryEntry object results in the following error & exception: `Unknown error (0x8000500c)` & `'P' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.
I noticed that the SearchResult object holds a byte[] object as a value of that property, while the other properties are simply strings. So, reading the SearchResult object is no problem, I can get the byte[] and convert it to a string if I want to. The problem is that I need to get this value, and copy it into another object in LDAP, and that is done using the DirectoryEntry object of the SearchResult object (I get it using the `GetDirectoryEntry` method).
Let me try to explain the problem:
In LDAP, I have two objects - 'A' and 'B'.
I need to copy a property 'P' from A into B.
Property 'P' comes as byte[] object (even though in JXplorer I read & update it manually as a string).
Trying to access a property 'P' from the DirectoryEntry object results in a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` exception; I think I read somewhere that it's related to the data type, that it doesn't know how to read/convert it (byte[]).

The property 'P' of the SearchResult object holds a byte[] (instead of simply a string, ideally, like the other properties: [image])

I'm unable to access the property 'P' from the DirectoryEntry object; I've shown in above SS that the property exists (I can also see the property name in the DirectoryEntry itself, but not the property value): [image]

I'm able to access any other property from the same DirectoryEntry object: [image]

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `P` property? Isn't this something systematic/something that is preventing write to it? Or is it some property specific for your LDAP/domain?

Comment: The property 'P' just holds some user data. Specifically, it holds some kind of user-defined PIN.

Comment: Is that property a custom attribute that was added to the AD schema? What is the data type in the schema?

Comment: And are you reading from an Active Directory domain?

Comment: @GabrielLuci  it's a custom attribute. Regarding the data type, it says in schema that the attribute's 'SYNTAX Description'
 is 'User Password Syntax', is that it? Regarding your last question - I'm not sure, I'm new with LDAP and Active Directory, I'm using JXplorer to read/update the data manually, and programmatically I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue on the same day I posted this question, by writing a custom class that handles the operations on properties that the current direct methods were unable to do. The methods can also be defined as extension methods, but I decided not to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Bell.ca.Services.UserServices.Ldap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Based on <see href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_property_operation_enum"/>
    /// </summary>
    public enum ADSPropertyOperationsEnum
    {
        CLEAR = 1,
        UPDATE = 2,
        APPEND = 3,
        DELETE = 4
    }

    public static class ADSPropertyOperations
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Clears the <paramref name="propertyName" /> of the <paramref name="directoryEntry" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="directoryEntry">The <typeparamref name="DirectoryEntry"/> to be modified</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property to be cleared</param>
        /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if operation was done successfully</returns>
        public static bool Clear(DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, string propertyName)
        {
            try
            {
                directoryEntry.Invoke("PutEx", new object[] { ADSPropertyOperationsEnum.CLEAR, propertyName, new object[] { } });
                directoryEntry.CommitChanges();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the <paramref name="directoryEntry" />'s <paramref name="propertyName" />'s value with <paramref name="value"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="directoryEntry">The <typeparamref name="DirectoryEntry"/> to be modified</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to set into <paramref name="propertyName"/></param>
        /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if operation was done successfully</returns>
        public static bool Set(DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, string propertyName, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                directoryEntry.Invoke("PutEx", new object[] { ADSPropertyOperationsEnum.UPDATE, propertyName, new object[] { value } });
                directoryEntry.CommitChanges();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appends <paramref name="value"/> to the <paramref name="propertyName" /> of the <paramref name="directoryEntry" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="directoryEntry">The <typeparamref name="DirectoryEntry"/> to be modified</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to be appended to <paramref name="propertyName"/></param>
        /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if operation was done successfully</returns>
        public static bool Append(DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, string propertyName, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                directoryEntry.Invoke("PutEx", new object[] { ADSPropertyOperationsEnum.APPEND, propertyName, new object[] { value } });
                directoryEntry.CommitChanges();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the <paramref name="directoryEntry" />'s <paramref name="propertyName" />'s specific <paramref name="value"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="directoryEntry">The <typeparamref name="DirectoryEntry"/> to be modified</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to be deleted from <paramref name="propertyName"/></param>
        /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if operation was done successfully</returns>
        public static bool Delete(DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, string propertyName, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                directoryEntry.Invoke("PutEx", new object[] { ADSPropertyOperationsEnum.DELETE, propertyName, new object[] { value } });
                directoryEntry.CommitChanges();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method I used to convert the property that holds an array of TV PINs as an array of byte[] into a list of strings:

```
private List<string> GetTvPinValue(SearchResult searchResult)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var tvPinProperty = searchResult.Properties["ssotvpin"];
    foreach (var item in tvPinProperty)
    {
        var tvPinBytes = (byte[])item;
        var tvPin = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tvPinBytes);
        result. Add(tvPin);
    }

    return result;
}
```